# Meteor, '/users/insert' is already defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, mongodb, meteor, collections

I'm creating basic Administration Panel and I didn't work with MongoDB yet.

For development purposes I left `autopublish` and `insecure` in the project.
In order to render users from database (`Accounts-ui` + `Accounts-facebook`) i need a handler for `Users = new Mongo.Collection("users");` but during compilation there is following error:

```
'/users/insert' is already defined.
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  {{> loginButtons}}

  {{#each users}}
    {{> user}}
  {{/each}}
</body>

<template name="user">
  <li>{{profile.name}}: {{_id}}</li>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Users = new Mongo.Collection("users");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.body.helpers({
    users: function () {
      return Users.find({});
    }
  });

  Accounts.onLogin(function(){
    console.log("logged in: " + Meteor.userId());
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

- facebook login is configured in another file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the user's collection is automatically defined you can't re-define it.

You can though reference the existing collection:

Instead of:

```
Users = new Mongo.Collection("users");
```

Use

```
Users = Meteor.users;
```